# R command to extract text between two strings containing curly parentheses

Tags: r, stringr, bibtex

I am trying to use the R str_match function from the stringr library to extract the title in bibliographical entries like the following. Indeed, I need to extract the text between the
`"title={" and the "},"` strings.

> a2
> [1] "@article{2020, title={Long noncoding RNA MEG3 decreases the growth of head and neck squamous cell carcinoma by regulating the expression of miR‐421 and E‐cadherin}, volume={9}, ISSN={2045-7634}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cam4.3002}, DOI={10.1002/cam4.3002}, number={11}, journal={Cancer Medicine}, publisher={Wiley}, author={Ji, Yefeng and Feng, Guanying and Hou, Yunwen and Yu, Yang and Wang, Ruixia and Yuan, Hua}, year={2020}, month={Apr}, pages={3954–3963} }"

I have used approaches like the following, but I get an error message:

```
str_match(a2, "(?s)title={\\s*(.*?)\\s*},.")
```

> Error in stri_match_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
> Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL, context=`(?s)title={\s*(.*?)\s*},.`)

I guess the problem is with the matching of the curly parentheses, but I couldn't make any progress. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex.

```r
a2 <- "@article{2020, title={Long noncoding RNA MEG3 decreases the growth of head and neck squamous cell carcinoma by regulating the expression of miR-421 and E-cadherin}, volume={9}, ISSN={2045-7634}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cam4.3002}, DOI={10.1002/cam4.3002}, number={11}, journal={Cancer Medicine}, publisher={Wiley}, author={Ji, Yefeng and Feng, Guanying and Hou, Yunwen and Yu, Yang and Wang, Ruixia and Yuan, Hua}, year={2020}, month={Apr}, pages={3954–3963} }"

sub("^.*title=\\{([^{}]+)\\}.*$", "\\1", a2)
#> [1] "Long noncoding RNA MEG3 decreases the growth of head and neck squamous cell carcinoma by regulating the expression of miR-421 and E-cadherin"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

Alternative `stringr` way.

```r
stringr::str_match(a2, "^.*title=\\{([^{}]+)\\}.*$")[,2]
#> [1] "Long noncoding RNA MEG3 decreases the growth of head and neck squamous cell carcinoma by regulating the expression of miR-421 and E-cadherin"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to parse a bibtex file, what you can do is to use `bib2df::bib2df`, with `reference.bib` being your bibtex file.

```r
install.packages("bib2df")
library(bib2df)

bib2df("reference.bib")$TITLE..LONG
# [1] "Long noncoding RNA MEG3 decreases the growth of head and neck squamous cell carcinoma by regulating the expression of miR-421 and E-cadherin"
```

Comment: Wow It doesn't precisely answer my question, but it is a terrific solution. I'll probably change  my whole script now to take in account your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_extract`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

a2 %>% 
  str_extract("(?<=title\\=\\{)[^\\}]*(?=\\},)")

#> [1] "Long noncoding RNA MEG3 decreases the growth of head and neck squamous cell carcinoma by regulating the expression of miR‐421 and E‐cadherin"
```

Comment: Also your solution does the trick.Appreciated.